# How to infer types from an array of arrays. I.e. Array<Array<Any>>

Tags: arrays, swift, types, type-inference

my program takes as input an array of arrays and every array could be of a different type. e.g.

```
var data = [[1, 2, 3], ["1", "2", "3"], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
print(type(of: data)) // Array<Array<Any>>
```

From each array in data I would like to automatically infer the correct type. Lets say that data always will contain arrays of either double, int and float. So my protocol is:

```
public protocol myType {}
extension Int: myType {}
extension Double: myType {}
extension String: myType {}
```

What I would like to do is store every array in data in a dictionary that conforms to myType
For examples

```
var dict = Dictionary<AnyHashable, Array<myType>>()
hashTable["0"] = data[0] // error
hashTable["1"] = data[1] // error
hashTable["2"] = data[2] // error
```

Ofcourse this doesn't work because data[0] is not of myType but of Any type. Is there an easy automated way to cast each array automatically to either int, double or string?

Answer (score 1):

Minor nitpick: The protocol here should be called `MyType` instead of `myType`, since convention is for types to start with a capital letter.

With that said, casting to `[MyType]` should do what you want:

```
var data = [[1, 2, 3], ["1", "2", "3"], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]

public protocol MyType {}
extension Int: MyType {}
extension Double: MyType {}
extension String: MyType {}

var dict: [AnyHashable : [MyType]] = [:]

dict["0"] = data[0] as? [MyType]
dict["1"] = data[1] as? [MyType]
dict["2"] = data[2] as? [MyType]

print(dict)
```

outputs:

```
[AnyHashable("2"): [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], AnyHashable("1"): ["1", "2", "3"], AnyHashable("0"): [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: But what use is this, we still don't know the type of each array in the dictionary other than it is either an array of Int, String or Double. Any operations on the array must first have to determine the exact type so this is no better than the original `data`

Comment: Well, it depends on what OP is trying to do here, but the common case for a protocol like this that you put some `wibble` method on the protocol, and then add implementations on each of the extensions such that each type now implements the `wibble` method. Then you can go through each collection, call `wibble` on each object, and use the return value of that without necessarily caring what the actual types of the objects are. It's one aspect of a concept called Protocol-Oriented Programming, which is a pretty big part of the Swift idiom.

Comment: I don't disagree with that but I think the intention was more to be able to identify and separate the arrays based on the element type

Comment: The OP was literally trying to store the values in a `Dictionary<AnyHashable, Array<myType>>` which is just the long form of `[AnyHashable: [myType]]`. I showed them how to do that. Also, it's the correct way to do this in idiomatic Swift, so ‍♂️

Comment: Yes but what OP is trying to do is not a good idea, it's basically a dead end. That is my point.

Comment: All you have to do is put the appropriate method on your protocol, and then it's a very good idea. It depends on what the OP is actually trying to do, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying to do with your protocol will make any difference, MyType will just be pretty much the same as Any but limited to fewer types. You will still not be able to perform specific actions based on the type of the underlying data.

Instead you need to determine the exact type for each sub-array and then act on that specific type like in the example below

```
data.forEach {
    guard !$0.isEmpty else { return }
    switch $0.first {
    case _ as Int:
        handleIntArray($0 as! [Int])
    case _ as Double:
        handleDoubleArray($0 as! [Double])
    case _ as String:
        handleStringArray($0 as! [String])
    default:
        print("Unsupported type")
    }
}

func handleIntArray(_ array: [Int]) {
    //...
}
func handleDoubleArray(_ array: [Double]) {
    //...
}

func handleStringArray(_ array: [String]) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are going the wrong way. Why would you need to mix collection types inside another collection? Anyway if you realy want to go down this path you need first to make your life easier fixing the main issue of your code that is the fact that you are working with `[[Any]]`. Change your collection type to `[Any]` and switch its contents.

```
let data: [Any] = [[1, 2, 3], ["1", "2", "3"], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
data.forEach {
    switch $0 {
    case let elements as [Int]:
        print("integers:", elements)
    case let elements as [Double]:
        print("doubles:", elements)
    case let elements as [String]:
        print("strings:", elements)
    default:
        print("other object(s):", $0)
    }
}
```

another option if you don't want to change your data type is to cast your array elements to `Any` when switching it:

```
let data = [[1, 2, 3], ["1", "2", "3"], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
data.forEach {
    switch $0 as Any {
    case let elements as [Int]:
        print("integers:", elements)
    case let elements as [Double]:
        print("doubles:", elements)
    case let elements as [String]:
        print("strings:", elements)
    default:
        print("other objects:", $0)
    }
}
```

If you would like to get a collection of specific type:

```
let integers = data.first { $0 is [Int] } as? [Int] ?? []
let strings = data.first { $0 is [String] } as? [String] ?? []
let doubles = data.first { $0 is [Double] } as? [Double] ?? []
```

---

```
extension Sequence {
    func firstObjects<T>() -> [T] { first { $0 is [T] } as? [T] ?? [] }
}
```

---

```
let integers: [Int] = data.firstObjects()   //  [1, 2, 3]
let strings: [String] = data.firstObjects() //  ["1", "2", "3"]
let doubles: [Double] = data.firstObjects() //  [1, 2, 3]
```

Or to get all sub collections elements of a certain type:

```
extension Collection {
    func joined() -> [Any] {
        flatMap { ($0 as? [Any])?.joined() ?? [$0] }
    }
    func flatMapped<T>(with type: T.Type? = nil) -> [T] {
        joined().compactMap { $0 as? T }
    }
}
```

---

```
let integers: [Int] = data.flatMapped()    //  [1, 2, 3]
let strings: [String] = data.flatMapped()  //  ["1", "2", "3"]
let doubles: [Double] = data.flatMapped()  //  [1, 2, 3]
```